# Oracle jobs running into each other

Tags: oracle, procedure, oracle-xe

I scheduled three insert procedures at around 3am. The first two were spaced out 10 minutes apart, but the third one was only 5 minutes apart from the second. The third procedure kept failing, and I assumed it might be because the second procedure was still running at the time. All three procedures insert into the same table.

Would the best way to avoid the jobs running into each other be to create a separate procedure that calls the actual inserts in order? Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DB.DATA_INSERT_ALL IS

BEGIN

EXECUTE DB.DATA_INSERT_1;
EXECUTE DB.DATA_INSERT_2;
EXECUTE DB.DATA_INSERT_3;

   EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       NULL;
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       RAISE;
END DATA_INSERT_ALL;
/
```

What I'm not sure of is: would doing it like this execute each procedure only after the previous is complete (this is what I want)? Or would it try to execute all three at once?

I am doing this on Oracle Express 11g.

Comment: Why are these three procedures rather than one? Do any of these jobs depend on the outcome of the previous jobs? Do the procedure share a common dependency?

Comment: Yes, calling it within a single procedure sequentially will definitely run it one after another. Note that  `EXECUTE` is an SQL* Plus command and will throw an error if used like you are using it. Just the procedure name is enough when included inside begin.

Comment: @APC, they are for different clients so I want to keep them separate.

Comment: @Kaushik Nayak, got it, thank you!